# center image in pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

What I'm trying to do here is to add an image to a blank pdf. So far I've done it, but I want the image to be centered. How can I do this?

Here is my C# code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(filepath, strFilename), FileMode.Create));
    doc.AddTitle("Document Title");
    doc.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Winniethepooh.png");
    image1.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
    if (image1.Height > image1.Width)
    {
        //Maximum height is 800 pixels.
        float percentage = 0.0f;
        percentage = 700 / image1.Height;
        image1.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
    }
    else
    {
        //Maximum width is 600 pixels.
        float percentage = 0.0f;
        percentage = 540 / image1.Width;
        image1.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
    }
    //image1.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
    doc.Add(image1);
    doc.Close();
}
```

And this is the output:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzaejXGgqBOAMzd0UlY2QWFXNms

What I want is that the image is centered on the page. Currently the image is on the top of the page.

I even set the image alignment, but why doesn't it center the image on the page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `SetAbsolutePosition()` in order to center the image.

Just add the following to your code before you call `doc.Add(image1);`:

```
...
...

image1.SetAbsolutePosition((PageSize.A4.Width - image1.ScaledWidth) / 2, (PageSize.A4.Height - image1.ScaledHeight) / 2);

doc.Add(image1);

...
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its a pleasure :)

Comment: what about centering an image rotated by 90 ?