# Creating a blank pdf and uploading an image to each page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, itext

I am new to file handling in asp.net core 6.0. I want to create a blank pdf and load images from the ImagePath list into it. Using the resources on the internet, I tried to create a blank pdf and throw it into it, but in vain.
I couldn't use pdfReader inside pdfStamper. It was the only resource on the Internet that I found suitable for myself.

Link to the question; [Converting Multiple Images into Multiple Pages PDF using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485886/converting-multiple-images-into-multiple-pages-pdf-using-itextsharp)

How can I do that my code is below.

```
public static string MainStamping(string docname, List < string > imagePath, string mediaField) {
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    var webRootPath = config["AppSettings:urunResimPath"].ToString();
    string filename = webRootPath + "\\menupdf\\" + docname + ".pdf";
    //            yeniisim = yeniisim + filelist.FileName;
    //            var fileName = "menupdf\\" + yeniisim;

    FileStream pdfOutputFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
    PdfConcatenate pdfConcatenate = new PdfConcatenate(pdfOutputFile);

    PdfReader result = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < imagePath.Count; i++) {
        result = CreatePDFDocument1(imagePath[i], mediaField);
        pdfConcatenate.AddPages(result);
    }

    pdfConcatenate.Close();
    return filename;
}
```

```
public static PdfReader CreatePDFDocument1(string imagePath, string mediaField) {
    PdfReader pdfReader = null;

    //C:\Users\hilal\OneDrive\Belgeler\GitHub\Restaurant\Cafe.Web\wwwroot\assets\barkod-menu
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    var webRootPath = config["AppSettings:urunResimPath"].ToString();
    string image = webRootPath + "\\barkod-menu\\" + imagePath;
    iTextSharp.text.Image instanceImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image);

    MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream();

    inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //I don't know what to do here do I need to use it?
    pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream);

    AcroFields testForm = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
    testForm.SetField("MediaField", mediaField);

    PdfContentByte overContent = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);
    IList < AcroFields.FieldPosition > fieldPositions = testForm.GetFieldPositions("ImageField");

    if (fieldPositions == null || fieldPositions.Count <= 0) throw new ApplicationException("Error locating field");
    AcroFields.FieldPosition fieldPosition = fieldPositions[0];

    overContent.AddImage(instanceImg);
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.Close();

    PdfReader resultReader = new PdfReader(memoryStream.ToArray());
    pdfReader.Close();

    return resultReader;
}
```

[image]

If I want to explain visually, the blank pdf I created will be uploaded in this way. Thank you

Comment: If you don't find any luck with your current approach I've found PDFSharp works well with PDF manipulation. here are some examples: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx  and then specifically for images: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Images_35

Comment: To add to that, I have been able to use images, create text, and pull apart and merge pdfs with this very easily. Most of the issues actually arise from the actual PDF format itself and all the different templates or data structures they try to use, so if you're making one from some images this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shows how to create a PDF using iTextSharp (v. 5.5.13.3), and add images to the PDF (one image per page). It's been tested with .NET 6.

**Pre-requisite**:

- Download / install NuGet package `iTextSharp` (v. 5.5.13.3)

**Add the following using statements**:

- `using iTextSharp.text;`
- `using iTextSharp.text.pdf;`
- `using System.IO;`

In the code below the PDF is saved to a byte array, instead of a file to allow for more options.

**CreatePdfDocument**:

```
public static byte[] CreatePdfDocument(List<string> imagePaths)
{
    byte[] pdfBytes;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f))
        {
            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
            {
                //open
                doc.Open();

                //create a new page for each image
                for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.Count; i++)
                {
                    //add new page
                    doc.NewPage();

                    //get image
                    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePaths[i]);

                    //ToDo: set desired image size
                    //img.ScaleAbsolute(100.0f, 100.0f);

                    //center image on page
                    img.SetAbsolutePosition((PageSize.LETTER.Width - img.ScaledWidth) / 2, (PageSize.LETTER.Height - img.ScaledHeight) / 2);

                    //add image to page
                    doc.Add(img);
                }

                //close
                doc.Close();

                //convert MemoryStream to byte[]
                pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }    
    }

    return pdfBytes;
}
```

I've decided that all I want to do is write the PDF to a file. The method below writes the PDF to a file.

**CreatePdf**:

```
public static void CreatePdf(string filename, List<string> imagePaths)
{
    //create PDF
    byte[] pdfBytes = CreatePdfDocument(imagePaths);

    //save PDF to file
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (filename, pdfBytes);   
}
```

**Resources**:

- [How to generate PDF one page one row from datatable using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69218085/10024425)
- [iTextSharp - Working with images](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images)
- [Center image in pdf using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161476/10024425)

**Additional Resources**:

- [iTextSharp: How to resize an image to fit a fix size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412504/itextsharp-how-to-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-fix-size/45773775)